# How to display result from async function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new in Node and I've watched some of the tutorials from the Net.
My main problem is how I can show the result from the route I created. Well, I'm getting the correct data using the console but when I access it through browser it doesn't show the json encoded data.

Here is my product.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../connection');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(products());
})

async function products(){
    // console.log(products)
    return await getProducts();
}

function getProducts(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
         connection.query('SELECT brand,description from products limit 100', function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err
            resolve(JSON.stringify(rows))
        })
    })
}

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the console log result : http://prntscr.com/llxgk2

Here is the result from the postman: http://prntscr.com/llxgy3

Comment: Since you're just starting out: You're missing `;` after `throw err`, `resolve(JSON.stringify(rows))`, and your `query` call. Automatic Semicolon Insertion will handle it for you, but you don't appear to be intentionally relying on ASI (some people do, **I** don't recommend it), so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder noted I'll always keep that on mind

Comment: your `async function products()` is pretty much pointless as it does nothing but forwarding a function call. You could write that function as `function products(){ return getProducts() }` and the behaviour would be the same. Or you just use `getProducts()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consume the promise. In your case, probably with `then` and `catch` handlers:

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    products()
    .then(products => {
        res.json(products);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...send error response...
    });
});
```

Note I've used [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) to send the response. You probably want to change your `resolve(JSON.stringify(rows))` to just `resolve(rows)` and leave what to do with the rows to the caller. (`res.json` will stringify for you.)

You might also look at [Koa](http://koajs.com), which is from the same people who did Express, which provides first-class support for `async` functions as routes.